# Bot doesn't detect a reaction/author form a filter (reactionCollector)

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

i'm creating a bot on discord and i try to do a help command with pages but when i try the command, it didn't edit the message for the specific page, like, the user reacts 1️⃣ but nothing happens, heres my code

```
if (comando == `ajuda` || comando == `help`) {
    const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setTitle("Comandos")
      .setColor("#5C009C")
      .setDescription("Páginas dos comandos")
      .addField("Página 1 - Discord", "``avatar, emoji...``")
      .addField("Página 2 - Diversão", "``coinflip, roll...``")
      .addField("Página 3 - Miscelânea", "``ajuda, choose...``")
      .setFooter({"text": `${message.author.username}`, "iconURL": `${message.author.avatarURL()}`})
      message.reply({embeds:[embed]}).then((m) => {
        m.react('1️⃣');
        m.react('2️⃣');
        m.react('3️⃣');
        const filter = (user, reaction) => {
          return user.id != '610429375854149642' || user.id === message.author.id && reaction.emoji.name === '1️⃣' && reaction.emoji.name === '2️⃣' && reaction.emoji.name === '3️⃣';
        };
        m.awaitReactions(filter, { max: 1, time: 15000, errors: ['time'] }) 
        .then(collected => {
          if (collected.first().emoji.name === '1️⃣') {
            const p1 = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
              //code of the embed p1
          m.edit({embeds:[p1]});
        } 
        elseif (collected.first().emoji.name === '2️⃣'); {
            const p2 = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
              //code of the embed p2
          m.edit({embeds:[p2]});
        }
        elseif (collected.first().emoji.name === '3️⃣'); {
            const p3 = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
              //code of the embed p3
              m.edit({embeds:[p3]});
            }
        })
          .catch(collected => {
          return;
        });
      });
    }
```

i don't know to must about javascript, so i did try nothing

Comment: What's your discord js version?

Comment: 13.6.0 but i can't update it or i will need to recreate my code

Comment: In discord.js v13 all `Collector` related classes and methods (e.g. `.createMessageCollector()` or `.awaitMessages()`) take a single object parameter which also includes the `filter`.  So you should use `m.awaitReactions({ filter, max: 1, time: 15000, errors: ['time'] })`

Comment: Although I would simplify that filter like this: `const filter = (user, reaction) => user.id === message.author.id && ['1️⃣', '2️⃣', '3️⃣'].includes(reaction.emoji.name)`